# jquery validation only for visible controls

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jquery validation for required field vaidation.

```
$("#registerform").validate();
```

This fires for the controls which are hidden too.

For ex.: When the user selects `Others` option in `How you find us?` in register form, its required to fill the textbox for others option.

But this fires even when the control is hidden.

How to do it in jquery validation?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I haven't used the jQuery validation before but according to [the doco](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) there's an ignore field that you can pass a jQuery selector to. By using the [:visible](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible) selector you should be able to do this.

I believe this is what you're after

```
$("#registerform").validate({ignore:":not(:visible)"});
```

Comment: Wouldn't .validate({ ignore: ":hidden" }) do the same thing? IMHO that's a bit easier to read.

Comment: @nillis - More importantly, it's also the current default.

Answer (score 3):

You may try to add `:visible` to the selector itself:

```
$("#registerform :visible")
```

Comment: That would make it validate the form if it was visible, not individual fields within the form.

Comment: This one helped me my selector is like so: $('input.required :visible').each(function() {...};

Comment: @fyjham that's not true, since both selectors are separated with space, `:visible` would take all visible elements inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

**Please also try this way**

```
 if ($(#registerform).is(":visible")) {
      $(#registerform).validate();
  }
```