# jQuery validation plugin not validating fields that are not displayed

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802177/jquery-validation-only-for-visible-controls) question but it was written in 2009, presumably since then they have decided to ignore hidden fields by default...anyone know how I can validate my hidden fields?

I have a custom invalidHandler to deal with the result and was seeing some strange behaviour, I now realise this is because some of my fields are hidden (using display:none). I have a tabbed form, hence some elements being hidden FYI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a small hack would be to call the validation before the tab change, if there are errors don't let the user change the tab.

Comment: Did you try   $("#myform").validate({    ignore: ":hidden" });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer...

I started looking at the validator plugin code and came across this:

```
$.extend($.validator, {
defaults: {
messages: {},
groups: {},
rules: {},
errorClass: "error",
validClass: "valid",
errorElement: "label",
focusInvalid: true,
errorContainer: $( [] ),
errorLabelContainer: $( [] ),
onsubmit: true,
ignore: ":hidden", 
...
```

So I set the option 'ignore' to an empty string and it works. I guess the documentation should be updated because it doesn't state that there is a default for ignore.

Thanks anyway.